# Using hash maps in Java to find frequency of characters in a string

Tags: java, string, hashmap, frequency, anagram

I am trying to make an anagram program where I match all the keysets of a hash map with their values. But my code does not seem to count the occurrences of the character beyond the first.

```
String a="aabbcc";
HashMap<Character,Integer> map= new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
{
    if(map.containsKey(a.charAt(i)))
    {
        int n= map.get(a.charAt(i))+1;
       map.put(a.charAt(i), n);
    }

    else
    {
        map.put(a.charAt(i), 0);
    }
}
    System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{a=1, b=1, c=1}
```

Comment: because you counting from zero.

Comment: `... else { map.put(a.charAt(i), 1); } ...` !

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "aaaabbbccd";
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(a.charAt(i))) {
                int n = map.get(a.charAt(i)) + 1;
                map.put(a.charAt(i), n);
            } else {
                map.put(a.charAt(i), 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{a=4, b=3, c=2, d=1}
```

Everything in your program is correct except the initial count which you have put as `0`. When you put a character into the map for the first time, its count should be set as `1` instead of `0`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at `map.put(a.charAt(i), 0)`. That 0 should be 1, because when you find a character for the first time, the count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Well of course you get this result :)

Each of the characters a,b,c shows up 2 times in your string.
Now for example, for the first "a" you will go into the `else` branch, because it is not contained in your map yet. An thus `a` will be mapped to `0`. And then for the second "a" in your string you will enter the `if` branch, because the key `a` is already present in the map. And the `0` will be incremented to `1`. And you end up with `a` being mapped to `1`. Same  thing with b and c :)